# PHP Serialized Object Explanation

Tags: php, serialization

My project communicates with an API that returns a string with a PHP serialized object. Normally, the response is a serialized array & there's no issue unserializing it. However, we just encountered an endpoint where it returns an object we had not encountered before and I'm not sure how to create a Class that can be used to unserialize the object.

This is what comes back from the API (just showing the part that is confusing):

```
s:8:" * _data";a:1:{
    i:4057353;C:25:"Transfer_Sales_Order_Item":201:{
        a:5:{
            s:8:"quantity";i:1;
            s:19:"id_sales_order_item";s:7:"4057353";
            s:4:"name";s:44:"Empacadora Selladora FoodSaver al Alto Vacio";
            s:10:"paid_price";d:796.13999999999999;
            s:3:"sku";s:15:"LI200HL37WWCLMX";
        }
    }
}
```

Full serialized string:

```
O:16:"Service_Response":8:{s:11:" * _success";b:1;s:17:" * _errorMessages";a:0:{}s:19:" * _successMessages";a:0:{}s:22:" * _validationMessages";a:0:{}s:18:" * _noticeMessages";a:0:{}s:14:" * redirectUrl";N;s:23:" Service_Abstract _type";N;s:14:" * _resultData";a:1:{s:24:"NotAvailablesForTracking";O:40:"Transfer_Sales_Order_ItemCollection_test":6:{s:19:" * _objectClassName";s:25:"Transfer_Sales_Order_Item";s:15:" * _idAttribute";s:19:"id_sales_order_item";s:47:" Vendor_Transfer_AbstractCollection _indexDirty";b:0;s:8:" * _data";a:1:{i:4057353;C:25:"Transfer_Sales_Order_Item":201:{a:5:{s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:19:"id_sales_order_item";s:7:"4057353";s:4:"name";s:44:"Empacadora Selladora FoodSaver al Alto Vacio";s:10:"paid_price";d:796.13999999999999;s:3:"sku";s:15:"LI200HL37WWCLMX";}}}s:17:" * _setDataStrict";b:1;s:9:" * locale";N;}}}
```

It seems like it's an array of Objects / Classes (?) that just has an array? I've tried to look for what the `C` symbol means, but no success. Any idea of what the structure of `Transfer_Sales_Order_Item` should look like?

My guess is because the original class implements `ArrayAccess`, but I tried that & unserialized still complained it didn't have a target to unserialize to.

For the moment we solved it by implementing `Serializable` on the class & the `unserialize()` method which gets the contents of the class as a serialized string. This then unserializes normally to an array & we went from there.

This is the code we're using to unserialize the string:

```
class Transformer
{
    public static function debugUnserialize($className)
    {
        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Cannot unserialize object %s', $className, 500);
    }

    public function transform($value)
    {
        $previousCallback = ini_get('unserialize_callback_func');
        ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', self::class . '::debugUnserialzie');
        $data = unserialize($value);
        ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', $previousCallback);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

After adding an empty class `Transfer_Sales_Order_Item`, PHP throws

```
Warning: Class Transfer_Sales_Order_Item has no unserializer
```

Note that this is not the exception from the `unserialize_callback_func` callback. So it doesn't even get there.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Checking that now - with linebreaks it doesn't unserialize past `_data`....

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Seems like you're right! I've deleted my comment as it makes no sense in the matter. :)

Comment: and simply preg_replace()'ing all the extra whitespace doesn't help.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Unserialize throws an error because it doesn't have a target class for `C:25:"Transfer_Sales_Order_Item"`. If you add a `Transfer_Sales_Order_Item` it still complains that there's no target and there's no property to map the array to. Very puzzling.

Comment: @Adrian, `C:` was replaced with `O:` in php 5.6, meaning the server sending back the serialization is pre-php5.6. it means that the data type is an object requiring an `unserialize_callback_func` to process the unserialization correctly. here's the docs on [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) containing examples of using the callback

Comment: How are you calling `unserialize()`? Are you specifying a 2nd parameter? Is the referenced class already available to the script (via include or autoload)? What actual error message(s) are you getting?

Comment: Post the serialization **without doing any editing for easy viewing**

Comment: @RiggsFolly it could be sensitive information and is not necessary to solve his problem

Comment: Not sensitive, just didn't think it was necessary & there's a lot of useless information. Posting the full thing now.

Comment: @Adrian I copied down your class and worked it in with my answer and it's working fine. See my answer and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this somewhere in your script and it should solve your problem

```
<?php
function unserialize_callback_func($fqcn){
    $explode = explode("\\", $fqcn);
    $namespace = implode("\\", array_slice($explode, 0, count($explode)-1));
    $className = end($explode);
    $dev = "
        namespace $namespace;
        class $className{

        }
    ";
    eval($dev);
};
ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', 'unserialize_callback_func');
```

once your ini_set is registered, it will call `unserialize_callback_func()` each time `unserialize` runs into an object that doesn't exist. However, it needs to be registered prior to calling `unserialize()`

this callback function will create a class named whatever you want, allowing unserialize to set each property as a publicly accessible property.

if `eval()` is not allowed on your server, you can define each class needed inside the function

### EDIT:

Since you gave me your class, and the full serialize string, I've fixed your class up. This is the script I used to test it all out:

```
<?php

$data = 'O:16:"Service_Response":8:{s:11:" * _success";b:1;s:17:" * _errorMessages";a:0:{}s:19:" * _successMessages";a:0:{}s:22:" * _validationMessages";a:0:{}s:18:" * _noticeMessages";a:0:{}s:14:" * redirectUrl";N;s:23:" Service_Abstract _type";N;s:14:" * _resultData";a:1:{s:24:"NotAvailablesForTracking";O:40:"Transfer_Sales_Order_ItemCollection_test":6:{s:19:" * _objectClassName";s:25:"Transfer_Sales_Order_Item";s:15:" * _idAttribute";s:19:"id_sales_order_item";s:47:" Vendor_Transfer_AbstractCollection _indexDirty";b:0;s:8:" * _data";a:1:{i:4057353;C:25:"Transfer_Sales_Order_Item":201:{a:5:{s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:19:"id_sales_order_item";s:7:"4057353";s:4:"name";s:44:"Empacadora Selladora FoodSaver al Alto Vacio";s:10:"paid_price";d:796.13999999999999;s:3:"sku";s:15:"LI200HL37WWCLMX";}}}s:17:" * _setDataStrict";b:1;s:9:" * locale";N;}}}';

class Transformer
{
    public static function debugUnserialize($className)
    {
        $explode = explode("\\", $className);
        $namespace = implode("\\", array_slice($explode, 0, count($explode)-1));
        $className = end($explode);
        $dev = "
            ".(!empty($namespace)?"namespace $namespace;":"")."
            class $className implements Serializable {
                public function unserialize(".'$data'.") {
                    ".'$this->data'." = unserialize(".'$data'.");
                }
                public function serialize() {
                    return serialize(".'$this->data'.");
                }
                public function getData(){
                    return ".'$this->data'.";
                }
            }
        ";

        eval($dev);
    }

    public function transform($value)
    {
        $previousCallback = ini_get('unserialize_callback_func');
        ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', self::class . '::debugUnserialize');
        $data = unserialize($value);
        ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', $previousCallback);
        return $data;
    }
}

$trans = new Transformer();
var_dump($trans->transform($data));exit;
```

#### EDIT 2:

you're receiving data serialized in that way because, when `serialize()` is called on a class, without implementing a serialize difference, it will pull out all of the properties in such a way that it looks like an array. I used part of your provided information to create a test script:

```
<?php
class Transfer_Sales_Order_Item {
    public
        $quantity = 1
    ,   $id_sales_order_item = '4057353'
    ,   $name = 'Empacadora Selladora FoodSaver al Alto Vacio'
    ,   $paid_price = 796.14
    ,   $sku = 'LI200HL37WWCLMX'
    ;
}

echo serialize(new Transfer_Sales_Order_Item);
```

will output:

```
O:25:"Transfer_Sales_Order_Item":5:{s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:19:"id_sales_order_item";s:7:"4057353";s:4:"name";s:44:"Empacadora Selladora FoodSaver al Alto Vacio";s:10:"paid_price";d:796.13999999999999;s:3:"sku";s:15:"LI200HL37WWCLMX";}
```

however using this class instead:

```
class Transfer_Sales_Order_Item {
    private
        $quantity = 1
    ,   $id_sales_order_item = '4057353'
    ,   $name = 'Empacadora Selladora FoodSaver al Alto Vacio'
    ,   $paid_price = 796.14
    ,   $sku = 'LI200HL37WWCLMX'
    ;
}
```

will output the class name prefixed to each property to show that the property belongs solely to the class.

```
O:25:"Transfer_Sales_Order_Item":5:{s:35:"Transfer_Sales_Order_Itemquantity";i:1;s:46:"Transfer_Sales_Order_Itemid_sales_order_item";s:7:"4057353";s:31:"Transfer_Sales_Order_Itemname";s:44:"Empacadora Selladora FoodSaver al Alto Vacio";s:37:"Transfer_Sales_Order_Itempaid_price";d:796.13999999999999;s:30:"Transfer_Sales_Order_Itemsku";s:15:"LI200HL37WWCLMX";}
```

and for consistency sake if it were changed to `protected`, an `*` will be prefixed to each property to show that the property belongs to all classes inside the class inheritance structure.

the reason for all of this, is a simple way of showing how the properties exist in a class, and a string representation to show such a thing.

Comment: Did you test it with the serialized string?

Comment: We already implemented a class that's being autoloaded and is empty. We end up with the same warning that the class has no unserializer. We don't know what the property should be that will contain the array as it's not in the serialization string.

We have access to the source code of the API, but we can't modify it. The original class uses magic methods to implement getters and setters for the properties and implements `ArrayAccess`. That's all I know.

Comment: Sorry, when I said we implemented `__wakeup()` I was wrong. We implemented `unserialize()` similarly to how you implemented it above. So yes, that solves it. You don't need to implement `unserialize_callback_func` though, you can just make sure the class can be autoloaded.

Comment: It still doesn't explain what the `C:25:classname:208{a:1:{}}` mean with no property definition for the contained array. I understand that `C` may have been replaced in 5.6 (which is not what the manual says), but it doesn't explain how an array exists inside an object without a property.

Comment: @Adrian the changelog of [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) does state that it was changed. I've edited my answer again to show a test run on how serialize works with classes